# Assistance with how to properly create an xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I'm working in c#, and I was needing to convert a .csv to xml. I pretty much got it down, and understand how to do it. However I'm struggling to have it right with how i need it setup.

```
XNamespace xNamespace = "urlhere";
        XElement newXML = new XElement(xNamespace + "WarehouseReceipts",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", "urlhere"),
            from str in csv
            let fields = str.Split(',')
            select new XElement("WarehouseReceipt",
                new XAttribute("Type", "WH"),
                new XElement("Number", fields[9]),
                new XElement("ShipperName", fields[10]),
                new XElement("ConsigneeName", fields[11]),
                new XElement("Items",
                    new XElement("Item",
                        new XAttribute("Type", "WI"),
                        new XElement("Satus", fields[0]),
                        new XElement("Pieces", fields[3]),
                        new XElement("Description", fields[2]),
                        new XElement("PackageName", fields[1]),
                        new XElement("Length",
                            new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[4]),
                        new XElement("Volume",
                            new XAttribute("Unit", "ft3"), fields[8]),
                        new XElement("Height",
                            new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[8]),
                        new XElement("Width",
                            new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[6]),
                        new XElement("Weight",
                            new XAttribute("Unit", "lb"), fields[7]),
                        new XElement("WarehouseReceiptNumber", fields[9])
                    )
                ),
                new XElement("MeasurementUnits",
                    new XElement("LengthUnit", "in"),
                    new XElement("VolumeUnit", "ft3"),
                    new XElement("WeightUnit", "lb")
               )
            )
          );
        return newXML;
```

Now, I will show you what the prints out in the console, so you can have an idea of how it comes out in the xml format.

```
<WarehouseReceipts xmlns="urlhere">
  <WarehouseReceipt Type="WH" xmlns="">
    <Number>"3519"</Number>
    <ShipperName>"4 NET NETWORKING CORP"</ShipperName>
    <ConsigneeName>"ACUAMAR"</ConsigneeName>
    <Items>
      <Item Type="WI">
        <Satus>"On Hand"</Satus>
        <Pieces>"10"</Pieces>
        <Description>"APPLE NEW IPAD"</Description>
        <PackageName>"Case"</PackageName>
        <Length Unit="in">"5.00"</Length>
        <Volume Unit="ft3">"0.60"</Volume>
        <Height Unit="in">"0.60"</Height>
        <Width Unit="in">"4.00"</Width>
        <Weight Unit="lb">"10.00"</Weight>
        <WarehouseReceiptNumber>"3519"</WarehouseReceiptNumber>
      </Item>
    </Items>
    <MeasurementUnits>
      <LengthUnit>in</LengthUnit>
      <VolumeUnit>ft3</VolumeUnit>
      <WeightUnit>lb</WeightUnit>
    </MeasurementUnits>
  </WarehouseReceipt>
  <WarehouseReceipt Type="WH" xmlns="">
    <Number>"3519"</Number>
    <ShipperName>"4 NET NETWORKING CORP"</ShipperName>
    <ConsigneeName>"ACUAMAR"</ConsigneeName>
    <Items>
      <Item Type="WI">
        <Satus>"On Hand"</Satus>
        <Pieces>"20"</Pieces>
        <Description>"APPLE IMAC "</Description>
        <PackageName>"Box"</PackageName>
        <Length Unit="in">"35.00"</Length>
        <Volume Unit="ft3">"273.40"</Volume>
        <Height Unit="in">"273.40"</Height>
        <Width Unit="in">"15.00"</Width>
        <Weight Unit="lb">"400.00"</Weight>
        <WarehouseReceiptNumber>"3519"</WarehouseReceiptNumber>
      </Item>
    </Items>
    <MeasurementUnits>
      <LengthUnit>in</LengthUnit>
      <VolumeUnit>ft3</VolumeUnit>
      <WeightUnit>lb</WeightUnit>
    </MeasurementUnits>
  </WarehouseReceipt>
</WarehouseReceipts>
```

That whats above, is incorrect, and i need it to come out how it is shown below.

```
<WarehouseReceipts xmlns="urlhere">
  <WarehouseReceipt Type="WH">
  <Number>WR-1-22</Number>
  <ShipperName>shipper</ShipperName>
  <ConsigneeName>consignee</ConsigneeName>
  <Items>
    <Item Type="WI">
      <Status>OnHand</Status>
      <Pieces>3</Pieces>
      <Description>description2</Description>
      <PackageName>Package type2</PackageName>
      <WHRItemID>2</WHRItemID>
      <Length Unit="in">4.00</Length>
      <Height Unit="in">4.00</Height>
      <Width Unit="in">4.00</Width>
      <Weight Unit="lb">6.00000000000000088818</Weight>
      <Volume Unit="ft3">0.11000000000000000056</Volume>
      <Model>model2</Model>
      <WarehouseReceiptNumber>WR-1-22</WarehouseReceiptNumber>
    </Item>
    <Item Type="WI">
      <Status>OnHand</Status>
      <Pieces>4</Pieces>
      <Description>description</Description>
      <PackageName>Package type</PackageName>
      <LocationCode>RCV01</LocationCode>
      <Length Unit="in">1.00</Length>
      <Height Unit="in">3.00</Height>
      <Width Unit="in">2.00</Width>
      <Weight Unit="lb">16.00</Weight>
      <Volume Unit="ft3">0.01000000000000000021</Volume>
      <Model>model</Model>
      <WarehouseReceiptNumber>WR-1-22</WarehouseReceiptNumber>
    </Item>
  </Items>
  <MeasurementUnits>
    <LengthUnit>in</LengthUnit>
    <VolumeUnit>ft3</VolumeUnit>
    <WeightUnit>lb</WeightUnit>
  </MeasurementUnits>
  </WarehouseReceipt>
</WarehouseReceipts>
```

Any assistance on where i went wrong, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two problems, one is that your CSV is denormalized, so you need to group up the CSV rows by `ShipperName` etc. Also that is not how you deal with `xmlns`, what you are supposed to do is add `xNamespace +` to every node name in your XML

Comment: you have to add xNamespace to every single node? i didn't see other people do that with xmls that have an xmlns. I only see them do it on the root

Comment: If you look carefully you will see that the default namespace is getting changed back to blank `""` on the second node `<WarehouseReceipt Type="WH" xmlns=""` If you could post a sample of your current CSV showing how it's ordered then we could show how it can be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I used beyond compare to find difference.  Not sure what you need help with.  See picture

[image]

You are doing too much in one statement.  See following :

```
            XNamespace xNamespace = "urlhere";
            string[] csv = null;
            

            XElement WarehouseReceipt = null;
            XElement items = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < csv.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] fields = csv[i].Split(new char[] {','});
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    XElement newXML = new XElement(xNamespace + "WarehouseReceipts",
                        new XAttribute("xmlns", "urlhere"),
                        new XElement("WarehouseReceipt",
                        new XAttribute("Type", "WH"),
                        new XElement("Number", fields[9]),
                        new XElement("ShipperName", fields[10]),
                        new XElement("ConsigneeName", fields[11])
                        ));
                    WarehouseReceipt = newXML.Descendants("WarehouseReceipt").FirstOrDefault();
                    items = new XElement("Items");
                    WarehouseReceipt.Add(items);
                }

            
            
                items.Add(new XElement("Item",
                    new XAttribute("Type", "WI"),
                    new XElement("Satus", fields[0]),
                    new XElement("Pieces", fields[3]),
                    new XElement("Description", fields[2]),
                    new XElement("PackageName", fields[1]),
                    new XElement("Length",
                        new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[4]),
                    new XElement("Volume",
                        new XAttribute("Unit", "ft3"), fields[8]),
                    new XElement("Height",
                        new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[8]),
                    new XElement("Width",
                        new XAttribute("Unit", "in"), fields[6]),
                    new XElement("Weight",
                        new XAttribute("Unit", "lb"), fields[7]),
                    new XElement("WarehouseReceiptNumber", fields[9])
                ));
                 WarehouseReceipt.Add(new XElement("MeasurementUnits",
                    new XElement("LengthUnit", "in"),
                    new XElement("VolumeUnit", "ft3"),
                    new XElement("WeightUnit", "lb")
                ));
            }
```

Comment: So what i need is the following: it has a node called "Items" and within is where multiple "Item" nodes go, in mine i'm having this problem where it creates "Items" for each "item" i have, when what i want is to create each "Item" inside of "Items"